# pageblocktable span two rows?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to structure the pageblocktable element to display on two rows?

Existing Layout:
[image]

Wanted layout:
[image]

Existing Code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt_myTable" value="{!esb_List}" var="ben" rendered="{!!serviceSession}">

                    <apex:column style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}" >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Account Benefit</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.id}" target="_blank">{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Election Status" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                            <img src="/img/alohaSkin/help_orange.png" title="{!$ObjectType.Employee_Session_Benefit__c.Fields.Election_Status__c.inlineHelpText}" height="14" width="14"/>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Election_Status__c}" rendered="{!!sessionEditDisable}"/>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!ben.Election_Status__c}" rendered="{!sessionEditDisable}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Paper Status" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="{!paperRender && !sessionEditDisable}" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender && !sessionEditDisable}" />  
                        </apex:column>

                        <!--
                        <apex:column headerValue="Incomplete Reason" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="{!incompleteRender && !sessionEditDisable}" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="{!!incompleteRender && !sessionEditDisable}" />  
                        </apex:column>
                        -->

                        <apex:column headerValue="Per Payroll Premium" id="Premium" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Premium__c}" rendered="{!!sessionEditDisable}"/> 
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Premium__c}" rendered="{!sessionEditDisable}"/> 
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Reduced Premium" >
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Reduced_Premium__c}" rendered="{!paperRender && !sessionEditDisable}" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Reduced_Premium__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender && !!sessionEditDisable}" />
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Adjusted Per Payroll Premium" >
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Adjusted_Per_Payroll_Premium__c}" rendered="TRUE" />
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Volume" rendered="{!showVolume}" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}"> 
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Volume__c}" rendered="{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Volume__c && !sessionEditDisable}" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Volume__c}" rendered="{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Volume__c && !!sessionEditDisable}" />
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Elimination Period" rendered="{!showEliminationPeriod}" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Elimination_Period__c}" rendered="{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Elimination_Period__c && !sessionEditDisable}"/> 
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Elimination_Period__c}" rendered="{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Elimination_Period__c && !!sessionEditDisable}"/> 
                        </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: You can use pageblocksection and split the table into 2 sections and show columns one below another. There might be other ways this is one way to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
<apeX:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageblockSection >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt_myTable" value="{!Account}" var="ben" >

                    <apex:column value="{!account.name}" >
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!account.name}">
                    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>                   
</apex:pageblockSection>

<apex:pageblockSection >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt_myTable" value="{!Account}" var="ben" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 10cm;">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Reduced Premium" >
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Adjusted Per Payroll Premium" >
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column value="{!account.name}"> 
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Elimination Period" value="{!account.name}"> 
                        </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageblockSection>

</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]